# Stopping form submit during onclick of an input type="image"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The reset action is performed by `input type="image"` and `onclick` calls a function called `resetForm()`.

When reset is clicked the form submit should not happen.  I tried returning false from resetForm() function and still it doesn't work. Please help me out.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of returning false in `resetForm`, use `preventDefault` in the click function:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // yaa!
    resetForm();
});
```

`return false` does also work, but when jQuery got a function for something, I usually stick with that.

Answer (score 2):

I will make sure that your function is properly returning false, make sure you have no syntax error in your JavaScript.

Good way to test this, try alert("Testing Return!"); right before return false.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use `return False;` as opposed to `event.preventDefault();`, you **must** put the return false *within* the event callback. So, it would need to be like this if you are returning false in `resetForm()`:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    return resetForm();
});
```

Even simpler, if all you are doing is running a function on click (thanks to JimmyP for that reminder):

```
 $('#myButton').click(resetForm);
```

In my opinion, it's cleaner, simpler, and involves less typing. All wins for me.

Comment: Why not just $('#myButton').click(resetForm);

Comment: That's totally valid too... ;) I'll update my post to include that option as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone else is describing a different way to do what I am suggesting which is:

```
onClick="return resetForm();"
```

Otherwise the onClick is calling without caring the return.

Answer (score 1):

There is an actual way of doing it. But it requires a few steps.

1. Define your ..
2. You need bind the click even of the input item. use jquery to do it.
3. write your function

binding:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#yourinputtypeid").on("click", {Parameter1 : "your parameter value"},    
   FunctionNameToRun);
 }
```

the Function.

```
function FunctionNameToRun(event)
{
event.preventDefault();
// the rest of your code
}
```

That's it. This should prevent the submission / reloading of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably be better to use `<input type="reset" />` rather than `type="image"`, because the latter has the semantics of `type="submit"` and the former seems to have the semantics that you're going for. You could also easily put an image on such a button as well and it would probably save you the trouble of having to write a JavaScript function.

If you want to continue using `<input type="image" />`, I don't think returning `false` from the `onclick` event will do anything. Since it has the semantics of submitting the form, the form will just be submitted. In order to counter that, you could maybe place an `onsubmit` attribute in the form tag: `<form onsubmit="return submitFunction();" />`. In the `submitFunction` you could then check which submit/image button was pressed and depending on that return `true` or `false`. Returning `false` here **will** prevent the form from submitting.